# Is it possible to add the rwd minicart to my own custom theme, and if so how could I do it

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd-theme, mini-cart

Is it possible to add the rwd minicart to my own custom theme? and if so how could I do it?

I have tried copying minicart.phtml and items.phtml to my own theme and trying to call minicart.phtml in my local xml but it doesn't appear to be working

Comment: Which theme are you used ?

Comment: yes,possiable.. i have done for a customer

Comment: i am using my own theme based on the base theme, how is it possible? thank you

Comment: it possiable.. Need to change code at js fie

Comment: can you tell me how to do the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

in your local.xml file add

```
    <!-- Header ====================================================================== -->
     <reference name="header">
        <block type="checkout/cart_minicart" name="minicart_head" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml" before="-">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart_content" template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.cart_promotion" as="cart_promotion" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Mini-cart promotion block</label>
                </block>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

In your template/page/html/header.phtml file add

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>
```

Copy checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml - checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml and checkout/cart/minicart.phtml in your theme